# as3 dictionary of arrays

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dictionary

My code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary();
dict[[1, 2]] = 1;
var dbg = dict[[1, 2]];
trace(dbg);
```

Output:

> undefined

Why?

How can I get

```
 set<pair<int, int> >
```

from C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I would not call `[1,2]` "pair of int", it is "array with 2 elements". `{ item1:1, item2:2 }` would look more like pair to me.

According to documentation [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) uses strict equals (===) to compare keys, so passing new array as key every time will not work for indexing (arrays are strictly equal only when it is exactly the same array, not an array with the same content).

Depending on your needs converting key to a string maybe good option:

```
var keyPair = [1,2];
var key = keyPair[0] + "_" + keyPair[1];
```

Comment: If I try the same code with first line: var dict = {}; it returns 1. But Objects can map only strings. What kind of magic is it?

Comment: it calls the toString() function automatically

Comment: @sergey, Read on how JavaScript deals with objects/array (as ActionScript is more or less flavor of the same language). In case of untyped object AS/JS need to call `.toString()` on key (which will produce the same string similar to "object[]" in most cases) and that string will be used to index fields.